# Issue with AjaxControlToolkit loading MicrosoftAjax.js script resource

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have deployed my code on 2 different servers. I am using the AjaxControlToolkit on my master page. The one server loads scriptresource.axd with headers having 2010 Codeplex and the other server loads scriptresource.axd with headers having MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js.

The one loading MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js gives the following error

Uncaught Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

I have looked through many articles on web but could not resolve this. My question is its the same files on both the servers and what should be causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding the following to the web.config.

```
 <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Also, verify if .axd files are configured for the website

Answer (score 0):

The AjaxControl Toolkit includes an extended version of the .NET script manager.  You can reference it e.g.:

```
<AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager Name="someName"> 
.
.
</AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Comment: Yes I am using that but have the same issue.<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
        </Scripts>
        <Services>
        </Services>
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

Comment: Are you referencing the AjaxControl Toolkit on the master page?  Make sure it's using the same prefix.  Note:  http://blog.thinkoriginally.com/2010/05/03/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts/

Comment: Yes its using the same prefix. I want you to understand that the same code works fine on one server and not on the other. And I am also not clear why different scripts are loaded on different servers

Comment: Bah, misread.  you said you are using '<asp:ToolkitScriptManager...'  When you reference the ajax control toolkit you need to give it a prefix other than asp.  I personally use 'ajax', e.g. :<%@   Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="ajax" %>